# How do I insert lines of a file randomly into another text file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm looking for a way to insert all lines from one file to another file randomly.
Elaborating, lets say I have 2 files:
`toinsert.txt`

```
insert1
insert2
insert3
```

and
`mainfile.txt`

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
...
```

The resultant file should look like the following where lines from `toinsert.txt` and `mainfile.txt` are randomly mixed up:

```
line1
insert1
line2
line3
insert2
...
insert3
...
```

Is there a way to do this easily in bash? Cheers!

Comment: Should the lines preserve order?

Comment: @KamilCuk Not necessarily, no. But would help in the process actually.

Comment: What have you tried? What research did you do?

Comment: Not really a bash expert, but I'm familiar with Python. It can be easily done by reading both the files into 2 different lists and using a `random.choice()` with `zip()` from both lists to build up a new list and write to file. But the only issue is I'm afraid of running into memory issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it trivially using the `shuf` command along with `cat`, e.g.

```
cat toinsert.txt mainfile.txt | shuf
```

That will combine the lines from `toinsert.txt` and `mainfile.txt` in a shuffled order. To write the result back to `mainfile.txt`, you will need to use an intermediate temporary file, e.g.

```
cat toinsert.txt mainfile.txt | shuf > tmp; mov -f tmp mainfile.txt
```

(of course make sure you don't already have a `tmp` file or it will be overwritten)

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Is there a way I can preserve the order? Not required, just curious.

Comment: You can but it would be a bit less efficient. What comes to mind is using `readarray` to read both files into separate arrays, Then you could loop over the `mainfile` array in order writing a random number of lines out (e.g. `0`, `1`, `2`, ...) and then write the next line from the `toinsert` array out. I'm sure there is a better way to preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically generating 3 random numbers with no repeats in the range of number of lines of the other file.

Like:

```
mainfilecnt=$(wc -l <mainfile.txt)
toinsert=$(wc -l <toinsert.txt)
# copy input to output
cp mainfile.txt output.txt
# get as many random numbers as lines to insert in the range of lines
shuf -i 1-"$mainfilecnt" -n "$toinsertcnt" |
sort |
# join numbers with lines
paste - toinsert.txt |
# Reverse to insert from the last line
tac |
# we have number of line to insert to and a line.
# So insert it at that line number.
while IFS=$'\t' read -r num line; do
     sed -i -e "${num}i"<(printf "%s\n" "$line") output.txt
done
```

or like:

```
# get as many random numbers as lines to insert in the range of lines
shuf -i 1-"$mainfilecnt" -n "$toinsertcnt" |
# sort reverse for inserting
sort -r |
# generate GNU sed script to insert numbers
sed 's/.*/&R'toinsert.txt'/' |
# Use xargs to pass generated sed script back to sed
xargs -0 -I{} sed {} mainfile.txt
```

[tested on repl](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/ModestDecimalTab#main.sh)

The scripts above have a bug/feature that the line will not be inserted as the first line, only as second. These are just very short scripts I have written to show the method - you should refine them for what you actually need.